# manipulating multiple select boxes on a website via python not triggering POST request

Tags: python, dom, select, onchange

I'm trying to programmatically manipulate an internal website via python. It's actually working for the most part, but I'm stuck trying to trigger a POST request after the value of each box changes. I can see in the Chrome debugger that a POST request is made after I click on a value in one of the select boxes.

For example, there are three select boxes and each one is dependent on the last.

1. When a value is selected in select box A, select box B is populated via AJAX.
2. When a value is selected in select box B, select box C is populated via AJAX.

The items in select box A are statically loaded when the page is loaded. I can iterate through those with no problems.

```
import win32com.client
ie = win32com.client.DispatchEx("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate("...")

# stuff to see if the page loaded...

boxAObj = doc.getElementById("selectBoxA")
for i in range(1,boxAObj):
    # I've tried this multiple ways - none have triggered the request
    boxAObj.options.selectedIndex = i

    boxBObj = doc.getElementById("selectBoxB")
    print boxBObj.length
```

The print statement always prints 1. There was a default value in the select box "Select...", so that's why the length is 1.

Here are some images of the site to show the behavior. The first one is after a fresh page load with nothing selected either by the mouse or via javascript.

---

[image: Fresh reload]

---

In this picture, I programmatically selected an item in select box A using javascript, but nothing was loaded in select box B:

---

[image: Javascript selected a value]

---

In this picture, I clicked the same value in select box A and you can see that select box B populated as expected:

---

[image: Clicked]

---

The last piece of information is that the select boxes have onchange events assigned to them. Is that the key to this problem?

---

[image: onchange]

---

Edit: I just found a post that shows obj.onchange() from javascript should do the trick, which works in the browser, but not from python. Should I try to eval the function in python? I've tried a few things, but nothing has worked yet. See below:

---

[image: onchange from python]

---

Comment: eval is a stupid thing to try - I realize that - but I have no clue what to do next.